# How do I bind a comboBox to a different ItemsSource than it's parent DataGrid's ItemSource in a UWP project?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am using MVVM and bind a `DataGrid` to an `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>`. I can successfully do that, however I want one of the `DataGrid` columns to be a `ComboBox` column, with items source `List<ComboBoxValues>`. Also another column must be a `ToggleSwitch` where a `Command` with parameter is fired when it's `IsOn` property changes value.

In the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> DataGridData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();
    public List<ComboBoxValues> ListValues { get; set; } = new List<ComboBoxValues>();
    public MyICommand<ToggleSwitch> ToggleSwitchToggled_Command { get; private set; }
```

The problem I am getting is that the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` `Binding` is overriding the `Binding` path for the `CombobBox`'s `ItemsSource`, as well as the `Command`'s `Binding`. `ListValues` and `ToggleSwitchToggled_Command` is looked for within `DataGridData`.

For example:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ListValues' property not found on 'UWPProject.ViewModels.DataGridData'. BindingExpression: Path='ListValues' DataItem='UWPProject.ViewModels.DataGridData'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'Object')

In Xaml:

```
      <controls:DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="All"
                         AlternatingRowBackground="Gray" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridData,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="TextOne" Binding="{Binding aPropertyOneInDataGridData,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="TextTwo" Binding="{Binding aPropertyTwoInDataGridData,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ComboBoxHeader">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListValues}"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding aPropertyThreeInDataGridData,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          PlaceholderText="Select Action">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ToggleSwitch_Header">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggelSwitch_Run"
                                              IsOn="{Binding aPropertyFourInDataGridData,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Toggled">
                                            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ToggleSwitchToggled_Command}"
                                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </ToggleSwitch>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

So I guess, the question is, how do I split the "source" or path where the `Binding` is looked for within the parent `DataGrid`. There are many `WPF` questions and answers on this, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552278/mvvm-databinding-datagrid-with-combobox-different-itemsource) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118934/itemsource-binding-on-combobox-inside-a-datagrid). however I can't use `DataContext`, as I get the error that "`DataContext is not supported in a UWP project`." I can't find a solution for a UWP project for this problem. Also, I am using MVVM and no code behind, so I don't believe I can use `x:Binding`. I don't want to use code behind either.

Please help.

Comment: Does the following answer work, and do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, we suggest use `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to replace custom celltemplate. Then you could use x:bind markup extension to bind list property directly.
Because `DataGridComboBoxColumn` ItemsSource property could not access data source sub property directly, If you already make `ListValues` property for the Page class, you could also use x:bind to access like the following.

```
<controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
    Width="*"
    Binding="{Binding p2}"
    Header="Link"   
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListValues ,Mode=OneWay}"
    Tag="Link"
    />
```

If you do want to make custom celltemplate, you could insert the ListValues property into your `CustomClass`. For more detail please refer [this case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837543/how-can-i-use-a-collection-on-the-data-item-row-of-my-windows-community-template/60842557#60842557).

Comment: its seems I can't use x:bind without code-behind/ properties in the Page's .cs file.  I want to strictly use MVVM, and thus no code-behind. Therefore I can't use x:bind.  I have my code using Binding, for the DataGridComboBoxColumn, the only thing now not working is, there are no values on load and no values in the dropdown list, it stays empty

Comment: Fine, you could give your view model a x:name and use x:bind to bind the specific property.

Comment: Need to make my ListValues static for it to work, is it possible to x:bind to a non-static list?  I need to have a static command then as well, and it will give me problems there too?

Comment: Could you make new  thread to description your problem, It's hard to solve your problem in your comments.

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu, I posted another question [Inline Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719125/why-does-xbind-expect-a-static-method-to-bind-to/65727689#65727689)